# how to check whether user inputed or not?

Tags: c++, input, output

I am trying to develop a program in which I need to check whether the user gave input or not at first. If the user gives no input, a block of statements have to be executed and if the user gives input some other statements are executed. Using getche() or getchar() requires you to provide input, but I need the program to execute even if no input is fed. Is it possible to do this?

Basically I decided that I will take in an input from the user and run a segment of code but if no input is provided I will run another segment and end of of program.
Cause I don't want to print any messages to the user like `cout<<"Do you wish to continue?(y/n)"; cin>>choice;`. Instead I want the program to under stand by itself that the user dosen't want to continue. My program algorithm looks like this-

```
1.Check whether the user gave an input or not.If yes execute <2> else execute <3>
2. Receive input from user. Execute a set of operations. Then again go to <1>
3. Display message "Application shutting down". Go to <4>.
4.End
```

Comment: And how would the program know if the user intends to provide input or not?

Comment: in the entire program you check for input only once and the rest of the function execute automatically(and quickly) all inside a loop.

Comment: so the program does not need to know whether I`ll provide input or not. I`ll simply press my key for input until I encounter the check for input inside the loop repeatedly which happens pretty quick(i hope) (I`m sorry if I`m wrong cause its only a month since I started learning c)

Answer (score 2):

In Linux you can poll `stdin`:

```
bool isKeyPressed(int timeout) {
    struct pollfd fds[1];
    fds[0].fd     = STDIN_FILENO;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN | POLLPRI;
    return poll(fds, 1, timeout) > 0;
}
```

On Windows there's something equivalent:

```
bool isKeyPressed(int timeout) {
    DWORD res = WaitForSingleObject(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), timeout);
    return res == WAIT_OBJECT_0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for end of file on `stdin`  using `feof`.